# What is wrong in my approach to create a list of integers using IntStream and forEach?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The naive code I have is:

```
class ${
    public static void main(String[] _) {
        final List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i++).limit(5).forEach(val -> ints.add(val));
        System.out.println(ints);
    }
}
```

where my expectation was to see the following in the console:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But the actual is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

It is probably something very simple, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the incremented value. You postfix incremented a local variable and returned the non-incremented value. Use `++i` not `i++`

```
final List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> ++i).limit(5).forEach(val -> ints.add(val));
System.out.println(ints);
```

**Edit** See John Kugelman's post about using non-mutating operations when programming in a functional style. Using `i + 1` will create a new primitive and not mutate the parameter variable.

Comment: Don’t use any construct that misleadingly modifies the parameter variable. Just use `i -> i + 1`.

Comment: In addition, you can replace `forEach(...)` with `collect(Collectors.toList())` and  not initialize `ints` separately.

Answer (score 35):

`i++` has the value of `i` *before* it's incremented. You need to use the prefix operator.

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> ++i).limit(5).forEach(val -> ints.add(val));
```

Actually, don't do that. There's no reason to mutate `i`, it's simply thrown away. Use the side effect free version. That's the whole idea behind functional programming, after all: avoiding side effects.

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(5).forEach(val -> ints.add(val));
```

For the specific case of a stream of consecutive integers you could replace `iterate` and `limit` with [`range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-):

```
IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(val -> ints.add(val));
```

And finally, it would also be better to collect the stream into a list rather than adding values with `forEach`. It directly expresses the intention to create a list, which again avoids side effects.

```
List<Integer> ints = IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using a postfix `i++`, instead of a prefix `++i` while passing on the value to `forEach`. Changing to the following shall provide you the expected output :

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(5).forEach(ints::add);
```

Aside, an alternate way of iterating and combining limit with Java9+ is using [`IntStream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate(int,java.util.function.IntPredicate,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)) with an `IntPredicate` as :

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < 5, i -> i + 1).forEach(ints::add);
```

Comment: Good you've mentioned Java9+'s `IntStream.iterate` overloaded version

Comment: The usage of both prefix and postfix increment operators is poor practice and misleading. They mutate a variable here that is a temporary only visible inside the lambda. The only thing that matters is the return value, just return "i+1"

Comment: @PauldeVrieze I guess you meant the first line of code, which was the first instinct post and agreed, you can see the improvement in the next line of code. Would update both though.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I also agree that the second way is better

Answer (score 1):

You could use a print to see what was happend:

```
final List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.iterate(0, i -> {
            System.out.println(i);
            return i++;
        }).limit(5)
                .forEach(val -> ints.add(val));
        System.out.println(ints);
```

In that case, the value of i always will be 0, because the increment occurs after the value is returned, the correct way is

```
final List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.iterate(0, i -> {
            System.out.println(i);
            return ++i;
        }).limit(5)
                .forEach(val -> ints.add(val));
        System.out.println(ints);
```